# Infinispan cache union query

Tags: caching, merge, lucene, infinispan

I have two caches with different types inside

Would like to do a paged query on both of them. So would like to pass in a sort/filter values and get content from both caches?

Is there a way how to do it without manually writing the merge and pagination?

Currently I can only do something like this:

```
val queryFactory = Search.getQueryFactory(cache)    
queryFactory.from(Class.getClass)
```

or

```
val searchManager = Search.getSearchManager(cache)
searchManager.buildQueryBuilderForClass(Class.getClass).get()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Searching across multiple caches is not supported and there are no concrete plans to support it. Neither the query DSL nor the direct Lucene API allow it. The workaround is to merge the search results yourself.

The main reason for this is each cache has its own separate set of indexes. So a search across caches would have to retrieve data from multiple indexes and perform a merge which is not efficient in current implementation, so this was left out for technical reasons for now.